# CORS No Access Control Allow Origin

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have a GP service that generates a PDF report in reportlab based on a country clicked on a web map. I've placed the HTML/Javascript document on our web server for testing, and it's working (although we can only generate one report at a time, but that is a separate issue). I've tried to place this code in an HTML widget on our website and test it, and I keep getting the "XMLHttpRequest cannot load  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." I've tried to follow every thread I've found on this (there are dozens) and added "add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" to the web config files on our proxy server and the arcgis web config in the wwwroot. I'm still getting this error when I run the tool. We have two other pages on our website that use a GP tool to generate charts and these pages do not throw up this error. I'm not sure how to get this working.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this to the config:

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />  
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />  
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
```

Comment: Thanks. Which config file? The one in the wwwroot folder?

Comment: web.config file

Comment: Right, there are two web config files, one on our proxy server and one in the wwwroot folder.

Comment: Actually there are three web config files in our wwwroot folder. Two for DotNet and one for the Arcgis web adapter. I still can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Just found this public CORS solution. I dropped this into the JavaScript and it works.

```
 (function() {
var cors_api_host = 'cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com';
var cors_api_url = 'https://' + cors_api_host + '/';
var slice = [].slice;
var origin = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host;
var open = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
var args = slice.call(arguments);
var targetOrigin = /^https?:\/\/([^\/]+)/i.exec(args[1]);
if (targetOrigin && targetOrigin[0].toLowerCase() !== origin &&
targetOrigin[1] !== cors_api_host) {
args[1] = cors_api_url + args[1];
}
return open.apply(this, args);
};
})();
```